# How to start implementing JMS in this simple scenario?

Tags: java, jms

i need to implement this scenario  Brief about that is
have two java based web application hosted on two different tomcat instances say T1 and T2. when ever there is content change on T2
i want to put content name and date modified in queue on which T1 is listening. As soon as T2 put it queue , T1 should  log these
fields in  databse table which three columns i.e prim key, ContentName  and Modified date.?  I am not getting how to start implementing
JMS here as i am  laymen to JMS? I just know JMS makes use of queue on which probably one application will be publisher and other will consumer.
Any help how to start on this would be immense favour? I am using tomcat for both application. On different sites on net there is two much material that it gets confused (Actually i have short time to implement this :()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calm down and start reading. There are a few short tutorials that don't go to extreme lengths to explain the theory before getting to runnable code. This is not a bad one: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/

Basically you obtain a connection factory from somewhere. (It could be by a JNDI lookup or you could create it directly.) You ask the factory to create a connection, the connection to create a session, and the rest comes from the session.

To send a message you might use something like:

```
   ConnectionFactory factory = getJMSConnectionFactory();
   Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
   Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   Queue queue = session.createQueue("MyQueue");
   MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
   connection.start();
   Message message = session.createTextMessage("hello world!");
   producer.sendMessage(message);
```

To receive a message you might use something like:

```
   ConnectionFactory factory = getJMSConnectionFactory();
   Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
   Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   Queue queue = session.createQueue("MyQueue");
   MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
   connection.start();
   Message message = consumer.receive();
```

Comment: Thanks Joni for bringing clarity. I have one more question how two java application on two different webserver will get handle to same queue. As you mentioned in your example  Queue queue=session.createQueue("MyQueue");  Where this queue object will be lying actually(i mean on producer side or consumer side) and how both server can access same queue?

Comment: The object that represents a queue is present in both sides. The queue itself is maintained by the message broker which may be an external program running on a different machine. JMS doesn't define any concrete wire protocol for clients connecting to the broker, so how the consumers and producers access the queue depends on the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a short time, then **skip JMS**, actually if you have a long time, **skip JMS**, it is not appropriate for your simple use case. A simple Servlet that takes messages and processes them would suffice.

JMS is an overly complicated overly generalized layer for something that should be much simpler. If you just **must** using some kind of queuing system, them consider something much lighter and simpler like using a direct client library for [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) or a [Stomp](http://stilts.projectodd.org/stilts-stomp-client/) client of some sort.

You could always go back in and add the overhead and complexity of a JMS client wrapper if you really feel the need, here is a hint you won't.